# Hours spent on a ticket in osTicket?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, osticket

I've hit a roadblock with this template. I've added a dropdown for number of hours spent on a ticket, but it currently doesn't do anything. I'd like it to add an entry to the database under the hours_spent column, but I can't get it to run my query.

```
<?php
global $cfg;

if (!$info['title'])
    $info['title'] = 'Change Tickets Status';

?>
<h3><?php echo $info['title']; ?></h3>
<b><a class="close" href="#"><i class="icon-remove-circle"></i></a></b>
<div class="clear"></div>
<hr/>
<?php
if ($info['error']) {
    echo sprintf('<p id="msg_error">%s</p>', $info['error']);
} elseif ($info['warn']) {
    echo sprintf('<p id="msg_warning">%s</p>', $info['warn']);
} elseif ($info['msg']) {
    echo sprintf('<p id="msg_notice">%s</p>', $info['msg']);
} elseif ($info['notice']) {
   echo sprintf('<p id="msg_info"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i> %s</p>',
           $info['notice']);
}


$action = $info['action'] ?: ('#tickets/status/'. $state);
?>
<div id="ticket-status" style="display:block; margin:5px;">
    <form method="post" name="status" id="status"
        action="<?php echo $action; ?>">
        <table width="100%">
            <?php
            if ($info['extra']) {
                ?>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td colspan="2"><strong><?php echo $info['extra'];
                ?></strong></td> </tr>
            </tbody>
            <?php
            }

            $verb = '';
            if ($state) {
                $statuses = TicketStatusList::getStatuses(array('states'=>array($state)))->all();
                $verb = TicketStateField::getVerb($state);
            }

            if ($statuses) {
            ?>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=2>
                        <span>

                        <?php
                        if (count($statuses) > 1) { ?>
                            <strong><?php echo __('Status') ?>:&nbsp;</strong>
                            <select name="status_id">
                            <?php
                            foreach ($statuses as $s) {
                                echo sprintf('<option value="%d" %s>%s</option>',
                                        $s->getId(),
                                        ($info['status_id'] == $s->getId())
                                         ? 'selected="selected"' : '',
                                        $s->getName()
                                        );
                            }
                            ?>
                            </select><br>
/**
Code I've added begins below
**/
                            <strong><?php echo __('Hours Spent') ?>:&nbsp;</strong>
                                <select required id="hours_spent" name="hours_spent">
                                <option value="">How Many?</option>
                                <<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 40; $i++) : ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                            <?php endfor; ?>
                        </select>
 /**
Code I've added ends above
**/
                            <font class="error">*&nbsp;<?php echo $errors['status_id']; ?></font>
                        <?php
                        } elseif ($statuses[0]) {
                            echo  "<input type='hidden' name='status_id' value={$statuses[0]->getId()} />";
                        } ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <?php
            } ?>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <?php
                        $placeholder = $info['placeholder'] ?: __('Optional reason for status change (internal note)');
                        ?>
                        <textarea name="comments" id="comments"
                            cols="50" rows="3" wrap="soft" style="width:100%"
                            class="richtext ifhtml no-bar"
                            placeholder="<?php echo $placeholder; ?>"><?php
                            echo $info['comments']; ?></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <hr>
        <p class="full-width">
            <span class="buttons pull-left">
                <input type="reset" value="<?php echo __('Reset'); ?>">
                <input type="button" name="cancel" class="close"
                value="<?php echo __('Cancel'); ?>">
            </span>
            <span class="buttons pull-right">
                <input type="submit" value="<?php
                echo $verb ?: __('Submit');?>">
            </span>
         </p>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
<table>
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    // Copy checked tickets to status form.
    $('form#tickets input[name="tids[]"]:checkbox:checked')
    .each(function() {
        $('<input>')
        .prop('type', 'hidden')
        .attr('name', 'tids[]')
        .val($(this).val())
        .appendTo('form#status');
    });
});
</script>
```

My question is twofold. What is the function that passes the user's input to the backend database and how can I piggyback off of that function to insert my own query to update the database with hours_spent?

Comment: You are displaying the front end view (HTML rendering) part here. Where is your program code?

Comment: The way that the data is passed to the backend is via the form submission. `<form method="post" name="status" id="status" action="<?php echo $action; ?>">` The file that $action ends up pointing to is the one that has the DB insertion code in it. Without seeing it, neither of your questions can be fully answered. ;)

Answer (score 0):

http://osticket.com/forum/discussion/76145/time-spent-mod

I ended up installing the mod above, works like a charm.